# Find and replace a string within multiple files contained within a directory using a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

My aim is to search for a string contained within multiple .config files that sits inside a directory.

The folder structure is like this: C:\Parent_Folder\child_folder\

The child folder contains many different folders containing a .config file within each folder.

I am trying to create a .bat file that will allow me to search all of these folders and then replace a certain string with a new string.

I have found a way to search all files and print this to a document showing me where the changes are requires using:

```
findstr /i /s "DATABASE1" *.config > c:\temp\Changes.txt
```

However when it comes to creating a batch file to search the directory and replace all these files  with a new string I am coming across the file path does not exist.

I have had a look at the following similar issues:
[Batch script to replace specific string in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542554/batch-script-to-replace-specific-string-in-multiple-files)

[Find and replace string in multiple files within a folder using windows Batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234650/find-and-replace-string-in-multiple-files-within-a-folder-using-windows-batch-sc)

The code I am currently using is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "dir1=C:\Parent_Folder\child_folder\"
set "search=database1"
set "replace=db2"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%dir1%\*.config") do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%configFile%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)

@pause
```

The error I keep coming across is that the specified path can not be found, I thought it may be due to environment variables so I added the path in there and displayed the `echo %PATH%` in the .bat file and the path does exist however I keep getting the error stating it does not.

So I am not sure if it is actually something else here causing the issue.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: What's the content of `%configFile%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want [[SS64]: FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html).

Small example:

*script00.bat*:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set _ROOT_DIR=".\dir0"

for /R %_ROOT_DIR% %%f in (*.config) do (
    echo file: %%f
    rem Do the rest
)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068684288]> tree /f /a
> Folder PATH listing for volume SSD0-WORK
> Volume serial number is AE9E-72AC
> E:.
> |   script00.bat
> |
> \---dir0
>     +---dir0
>     |       file.config
>     |
>     +---dir1
>     |       file.config
>     |
>     \---dir2
>             file.config
>
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068684288]> script00.bat
> file: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068684288\dir0\dir0\file.config
> file: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068684288\dir0\dir1\file.config
> file: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068684288\dir0\dir2\file.config
> ```